# Action aggregations broken?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, aggregation

Since yesterday evening around 7pm EST, I have not been able to create aggregations where "Data To Display" refers to an action.

For my action 'Sit', I keep getting this error when trying to save :

"There is no way to use the selectors '' from 'Sit'. Make sure there is a path from your Action Type to your Object Type with depth ≤ 3."

This occurs regardless of the type of Layout Style or the values for Aggregation Title and Caption.

No filters are being applied in Advanced Options.